# How to assign Class to data retrieved from Firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the code, in which I retrieve data from Firestore.

```
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private DocumentReference dataRef = db.collection("users").document(currentUser);

    dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    navUserName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fullname"));
                    navGmail.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
                } else {
                    Log.i("current user data: ","Not Found");
                }
            }
        });
```

I want to assign this data first to class user object and then want to retrieve it from class user object. How can I do this?

Comment: The code you shared, works? Do you have a POJO class for your user?

Comment: I know it's work. But how to assign data directly to class.

Comment: Do you have a POJO class for your user?

Comment: I do not know what is pojo class. But I have a normal 'user' class. I upload data in following way. FirebaseFireStore db = FirebaseFireStore.getInstance(); db.collection("users").document(useruid).set(user);. user inside set is the object of user class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, if you are adding the data to the database using a `User` object, to get the data back, you can map the `DocumentSnapshot` object to a `User` object using the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DocumentReference dataRef = db.collection("users").document(uid);
dataRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
        Log.d(TAG, user.getFullname());
    }
});
```